# How do I share links to album in the U1 music store?

Tags: ubuntu-one, unity-dash, music

First of all I open the dash and click the musical note icon. Then I search for an album or song. Now I've found it I want to send a link to my friend on facebook/twitter/google+. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't currently a way to do this. We used to have a feature in the plug-in for Rhythmbox, to share a link directly via Gwibber, but due to time and other constraints, we had to remove the feature while porting the plug-in to the new version of Rhythmbox, and all the related newer APIs.

Perhaps it is something we can bring back in Ubuntu 12.10 though. I do have a few ideas about how we could make it better than it used to be.

Comment: I see. I don't really want to use gwibber. I just want to get the http link to the album in the clipboard so I can paste it wherever. Surely that should be easier?

Comment: For example https://one.ubuntu.com/music/l/1501818/0

Comment: @AlistairBuxton Right, I understood what you meant. The feature previously didn't require Gwibber to work. Without Gwibber installed, it would just pop a dialog with the URL, IIRC. However, all of this feature was removed for 12.04, due to the various constraints.